# SQL value not in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sql server 2005.
I have the following field called referenceInfo. If the length is more than 11 then is the identity number. If the length is smaller than 12 then is a approval.

The problem is it will jump to a second row. How do I make it in the same row?

http://postimg.org/image/8h4njmfsp/

```
CASE
    WHEN LEN(CONVERT(varchar(12), GUEST_CHECK_LINE_ITEM_HIST.referenceInfo)) > 11 THEN (+'"') + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(12), GUEST_CHECK_LINE_ITEM_HIST.referenceInfo)) + '"'
    ELSE '""'
  END AS [Identity Number],
  CASE
    WHEN LEN(CONVERT(varchar(12), GUEST_CHECK_LINE_ITEM_HIST.referenceInfo)) < 12 THEN (+'"') + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(12), GUEST_CHECK_LINE_ITEM_HIST.referenceInfo)) + '"'
    ELSE '""'
  END AS [ApprovalCode]
```

Thanks

Comment: please post sample values for referenceInfo column in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but it seems you are trying to merge two rows into one. Since you didn't give the full sql, try something like this (guessing that `ReceiptNo` is unique). It takes either `t1` or `t2` for both fields:

```
select all_other_fields
,      max(case
       when len(convert(varchar(12), t1.referenceinfo)) > 11 then (+'"') + rtrim(convert(varchar(12), t1.referenceinfo)) + '"'
       when len(convert(varchar(12), t2.referenceinfo)) > 11 then (+'"') + rtrim(convert(varchar(12), t2.referenceinfo)) + '"'
       else '""'
       end) as [identity number]
,      max(case
       when len(convert(varchar(12), t1.referenceinfo)) < 12 then (+'"') + rtrim(convert(varchar(12), t1.referenceinfo)) + '"'
       when len(convert(varchar(12), t2.referenceinfo)) < 12 then (+'"') + rtrim(convert(varchar(12), t2.referenceinfo)) + '"'
       else '""'
       end) as [approvalcode]
from   guest_check_line_item_hist t1
join   guest_check_line_item_hist t2
on     t1.ReceiptNo = t2.ReceiptNo
group
by     all_other_fields
```

Comment: this is the referenceInfo table value http://postimg.org/image/cekv20rpf/ I am trying to move the 100000001113 to identitynumber 106166 to ApprovalCode in the same row.

Comment: I am trying using your provided code but the result become like this http://postimg.org/image/uwbllfe6b/

Comment: @alexcctan: Then you have to use `group by`. Replace `all_other_fields` in the updated query with the other fields in your `select`.

Comment: Hi patrick, what do you mean by Replace all_other_fields in the updated query ?

Comment: In your picture, you have other fields that are in the query, like `MerchantId`, etc. Replace that in my sample.

Comment: Hi, it seems the provided code works. BTW, how do filter it only query the highlighted row? http://postimg.org/image/vozol1997/ excluded all t1 and t2 null value. Thanks

Comment: You could create a `select` around it and check with a `where`  If this is giving trouble, please add a new question.